# How to convert in Oracle numbers like ,26 in 0,26

Tags: sql, oracle

I try

```
select smth from tableuno
```

where **smth** is a number < 1, like **,26**. Which SQL function I need to use to convert **,26** to **0,26**?

**smth** can be **,26** or **2345,34** or **2323,345**. And I need **0,26**, **2345,34** and **2323,34**.

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(smth, '0.00') from tableuno;
```

This select statement fills a leading blank if the number is positive. So, if you don't want that, use the `fm` modifier of `to_char`:

```
select to_char(smth, 'fm0.00') from tableuno;
```

For values larger then 1 (such as *231423424,9877*) you can use go with leading nines:`to_char(smth,'99999999990.00')`.

Finally, as Alex Poole pointed out, there's the `D` to preserve your decimal seperator: `to_char(smth, '99999999990D00')`.

Comment: Maybe use `D` instead of a period, to preserve the session decimal separator as a comma here?

Comment: Yes, I used -  select to_char(smth,'99999999990.00') from dual. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrey Kargashinskiy: As Alex mentioned, you should probably use D for the comma instead: `to_char(smth,'FM99999999990D00')`.

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(smth, '0.99') from dual